# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference

Tags: android

I getting error as `null pointer exception` but as per my check, cycle flow is ok. 
i get error on this code

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), MapId.getId(mapName));
mIndiaBitmapLoadedListener.onIndiaBimapLoaded(bitmap);
map.setImageBitmapReset(bitmap, true);
```

This is my `MapId` class

```
 public class MapId 
    {
        public static HashMap<String,Integer> mapids = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        public static void setHashMap()
        {       
            mapids.put("Political Map",R.drawable.indiapoliticalbig);
            mapids.put("Physical Map",R.drawable.physicalmap);
            mapids.put("Railway Map", R.drawable.railwaymap);
            mapids.put("Road Map", R.drawable.roadmap);
            mapids.put("Tourist Map", R.drawable.touristmap);
        }
        public static int getId(String stateName)
        {
            return mapids.get(stateName);
        }
    }
```

This is my `Error log`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
    at com.compare.IndiaAtlas.MapId.getId(MapId.java:58)
    at com.compare.IndiaAtlas.IndiaFragment.onCreateView(IndiaFragment.java:62)
    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:894)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:834)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1454)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:447)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

we add three new entry in `sethashmap()` `Railway Map`, `Road Map` & `Tourist Map` these are get `error` but previous entry Physical and Political Map is Running properly.

Comment: I like the fact that your error states `Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference`, however the relevant code exists nowhere in the post. Voting to close as duplicate, and if I could, for lack of context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should initialize your map like this:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MapId {
    private static Map<String, Integer> mapids;
    static {
        mapids = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        mapids.put("Political Map", R.drawable.indiapoliticalbig);
        mapids.put("Physical Map", R.drawable.physicalmap);
        mapids.put("Railway Map", R.drawable.railwaymap);
        mapids.put("Road Map", R.drawable.roadmap);
        mapids.put("Tourist Map", R.drawable.touristmap);
        mapids = Collections.unmodifiableMap(mapids);
    }
    public static int getId(String stateName) {
        if (mapids.containsKey(stateName)) {
            return mapids.get(stateName);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And then just use:
`MapId.getId("Tourist Map");`

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<String,Integer> to HashMap<String,Integer>

Comment: I've edited the code.

Comment: using this code belongs classes get errors.

Comment: I think your NullPointerException was because you were trying to get the id of a stateName that the map does not contain. I have just updated the code to watch for that.

Comment: removed null object reference exception but have new Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'float android.graphics.RectF.top' on a null object reference.